# add a click function on GLmol (webGL)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, three.js, webgl

GLmol - Molecular Viewer on WebGL/Javascript: 
http://webglmol.sourceforge.jp/index-en.html

demo: http://webglmol.sourceforge.jp/glmol/viewer.html

However, **I want to add a click function**,such as click a ball, I will get some information about it. What need to do to realize this, could you give me some methods or advice

Comment: Does GLmol support Ray-casting mechanism? If it has Ray-casting, you can use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example in the threejs examples.
[Here is an example](http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/canvas_interactive_cubes.html)